# Android translate MotionEvent coordinates when drawing

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, zooming, draw

Hello i try to make some drawing after user zooms the view and have some issue.
Ive got a ZoomView (custom view) that contains a subview ImageView with the image (custom view),
ZoomView is working good, im able to zoom/pan/drag and the ImageView (custom) responds good to gesture, when i try to draw on ImageView after zoomed/dragged/panned ZoomView the drawn on touch gets a little messed.

[image]

first Top line is drawn when ZoomView is not zoomed, the line looks good.
second line is drawn when ZoomView is at middle zoom.
third is drawn at full zoom.

the issue is when zoomed and touching with finger, the line draws faster than normal, and you cant get a good line, he will always add some other line in this case (second line: extra line going to top , and third line: extra line going to bottom) while i was try to draw a line.

Im asking for help: how i can translate the touch point from ZoomView when is zoomed to the ImageView touch points to draw the canvas.

Here are my classes:

```
public class OwnZoom extends FrameLayout {

/**
 * Zooming view listener interface.
 * 
 * @author karooolek
 * 
 */
public interface OwnZoomListener {

    void onZoomStarted(float zoom, float zoomx, float zoomy);

    void onZooming(float zoom, float zoomx, float zoomy);

    void onZoomEnded(float zoom, float zoomx, float zoomy);
}
boolean modedown=false;
// zooming
float zoom = 1.0f;
float maxZoom = 2.0f;
float smoothZoom = 1.0f;
float zoomX, zoomY;
float smoothZoomX, smoothZoomY;
private boolean scrolling; // NOPMD by karooolek on 29.06.11 11:45

// minimap variables
private boolean showMinimap = false;
private int miniMapColor = Color.BLACK;
private int miniMapHeight = -1;
private String miniMapCaption;
private float miniMapCaptionSize = 10.0f;
private int miniMapCaptionColor = Color.WHITE;

// touching variables
private long lastTapTime;
private float touchStartX, touchStartY;
private float touchLastX, touchLastY;
private float startd;
private boolean pinching;
private float lastd;
private float lastdx1, lastdy1;
private float lastdx2, lastdy2;

// drawing
private final Matrix m = new Matrix();
private final Paint p = new Paint();

// listener
OwnZoomListener listener;

private Bitmap ch;

    public void setZommMode(boolean zoomed){
        this.modedown=zoomed;
    }
public OwnZoom(final Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public float getZoom() {
    return zoom;
}

public float getMaxZoom() {
    return maxZoom;
}

public void setMaxZoom(final float maxZoom) {
    if (maxZoom < 1.0f) {
        return;
    }

    this.maxZoom = maxZoom;
}

public void setMiniMapEnabled(final boolean showMiniMap) {
    this.showMinimap = showMiniMap;
}

public boolean isMiniMapEnabled() {
    return showMinimap;
}

public void setMiniMapHeight(final int miniMapHeight) {
    if (miniMapHeight < 0) {
        return;
    }
    this.miniMapHeight = miniMapHeight;
}

public int getMiniMapHeight() {
    return miniMapHeight;
}

public void setMiniMapColor(final int color) {
    miniMapColor = color;
}

public int getMiniMapColor() {
    return miniMapColor;
}

public String getMiniMapCaption() {
    return miniMapCaption;
}

public void setMiniMapCaption(final String miniMapCaption) {
    this.miniMapCaption = miniMapCaption;
}

public float getMiniMapCaptionSize() {
    return miniMapCaptionSize;
}

public void setMiniMapCaptionSize(final float size) {
    miniMapCaptionSize = size;
}

public int getMiniMapCaptionColor() {
    return miniMapCaptionColor;
}

public void setMiniMapCaptionColor(final int color) {
    miniMapCaptionColor = color;
}

public void zoomTo(final float zoom, final float x, final float y) {
    this.zoom = Math.min(zoom, maxZoom);
    zoomX = x;
    zoomY = y;
    smoothZoomTo(this.zoom, x, y);
}

public void smoothZoomTo(final float zoom, final float x, final float y) {
    smoothZoom = clamp(1.0f, zoom, maxZoom);
    smoothZoomX = x;
    smoothZoomY = y;
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onZoomStarted(smoothZoom, x, y);
    }
}

public OwnZoomListener getListener() {
    return listener;
}

public void setListner(final OwnZoomListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public float getZoomFocusX() {
    return zoomX * zoom;
}

public float getZoomFocusY() {
    return zoomY * zoom;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
    // single touch
    if (ev.getPointerCount() == 1) {
        processSingleTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    // // double touch
    if (ev.getPointerCount() == 2) {
        processDoubleTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    // redraw
    getRootView().invalidate();
    invalidate();

    return true;
}

private void processSingleTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
    //if(!modedown){
    final float x = ev.getX();
    final float y = ev.getY();

    final float w = miniMapHeight * (float) getWidth() / getHeight();
    final float h = miniMapHeight;
    final boolean touchingMiniMap = x >= 10.0f && x <= 10.0f + w && y >= 10.0f && y <= 10.0f + h;

    if (showMinimap && smoothZoom > 1.0f && touchingMiniMap) {
        processSingleTouchOnMinimap(ev);
    } else {
        processSingleTouchOutsideMinimap(ev);
    }
    //}else if(modedown){
    //  Log.i("moded own ", "is false");
   // }
}

private void processSingleTouchOnMinimap(final MotionEvent ev) {
    final float x = ev.getX();
    final float y = ev.getY();

    final float w = miniMapHeight * (float) getWidth() / getHeight();
    final float h = miniMapHeight;
    final float zx = (x - 10.0f) / w * getWidth();
    final float zy = (y - 10.0f) / h * getHeight();
    smoothZoomTo(smoothZoom, zx, zy);
}

private void processSingleTouchOutsideMinimap(final MotionEvent ev) {
    final float x = ev.getX();
    final float y = ev.getY();
    float lx = x - touchStartX;
    float ly = y - touchStartY;
    final float l = (float) Math.hypot(lx, ly);
    float dx = x - touchLastX;
    float dy = y - touchLastY;
    touchLastX = x;
    touchLastY = y;

    switch (ev.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        touchStartX = x;
        touchStartY = y;
        touchLastX = x;
        touchLastY = y;
        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;
        lx = 0;
        ly = 0;
        scrolling = false;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if(modedown){
        if (scrolling || (smoothZoom > 1.0f && l > 30.0f)) {
            if (!scrolling) {
                scrolling = true;
                ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            }
            smoothZoomX -= dx / zoom;
            smoothZoomY -= dy / zoom;
            return;
        }
        }else if(!modedown){
            ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
            super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            return;
        }


        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        // tap
        if (l < 30.0f) {
            // check double tap
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTapTime < 500) {
                if (smoothZoom == 1.0f) {
                    smoothZoomTo(maxZoom, x, y);
                } else {
                    smoothZoomTo(1.0f, getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f);
                }
                lastTapTime = 0;
                ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
                return;
            }

            lastTapTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            performClick();
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    ev.setLocation(zoomX + (x - 0.5f * getWidth()) / zoom, zoomY + (y - 0.5f * getHeight()) / zoom);

    ev.getX();
    ev.getY();

    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}

private void processDoubleTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
    final float x1 = ev.getX(0);
    final float dx1 = x1 - lastdx1;
    lastdx1 = x1;
    final float y1 = ev.getY(0);
    final float dy1 = y1 - lastdy1;
    lastdy1 = y1;
    final float x2 = ev.getX(1);
    final float dx2 = x2 - lastdx2;
    lastdx2 = x2;
    final float y2 = ev.getY(1);
    final float dy2 = y2 - lastdy2;
    lastdy2 = y2;

    // pointers distance
    final float d = (float) Math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
    final float dd = d - lastd;
    lastd = d;
    final float ld = Math.abs(d - startd);

    Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        startd = d;
        pinching = false;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (pinching || ld > 30.0f) {
            pinching = true;
            final float dxk = 0.5f * (dx1 + dx2);
            final float dyk = 0.5f * (dy1 + dy2);
            smoothZoomTo(Math.max(1.0f, zoom * d / (d - dd)), zoomX - dxk / zoom, zoomY - dyk / zoom);
        }

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    default:
        pinching = false;
        break;
    }

    ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}

private float clamp(final float min, final float value, final float max) {
    return Math.max(min, Math.min(value, max));
}

private float lerp(final float a, final float b, final float k) {
    return a + (b - a) * k;
}

private float bias(final float a, final float b, final float k) {
    return Math.abs(b - a) >= k ? a + k * Math.signum(b - a) : b;
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    // do zoom
    zoom = lerp(bias(zoom, smoothZoom, 0.05f), smoothZoom, 0.2f);
    smoothZoomX = clamp(0.5f * getWidth() / smoothZoom, smoothZoomX, getWidth() - 0.5f * getWidth() / smoothZoom);
    smoothZoomY = clamp(0.5f * getHeight() / smoothZoom, smoothZoomY, getHeight() - 0.5f * getHeight() / smoothZoom);

    zoomX = lerp(bias(zoomX, smoothZoomX, 0.1f), smoothZoomX, 0.35f);
    zoomY = lerp(bias(zoomY, smoothZoomY, 0.1f), smoothZoomY, 0.35f);
    if (zoom != smoothZoom && listener != null) {
        listener.onZooming(zoom, zoomX, zoomY);
    }

    final boolean animating = Math.abs(zoom - smoothZoom) > 0.0000001f
            || Math.abs(zoomX - smoothZoomX) > 0.0000001f || Math.abs(zoomY - smoothZoomY) > 0.0000001f;

    // nothing to draw
    if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    // prepare matrix
    m.setTranslate(0.5f * getWidth(), 0.5f * getHeight());
    m.preScale(zoom, zoom);
    m.preTranslate(-clamp(0.5f * getWidth() / zoom, zoomX, getWidth() - 0.5f * getWidth() / zoom),
            -clamp(0.5f * getHeight() / zoom, zoomY, getHeight() - 0.5f * getHeight() / zoom));

    // get view
    final View v = getChildAt(0);
    m.preTranslate(v.getLeft(), v.getTop());

    // get drawing cache if available
    if (animating && ch == null && isAnimationCacheEnabled()) {
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        ch = v.getDrawingCache();
    }

    // draw using cache while animating
    if (animating && isAnimationCacheEnabled() && ch != null) {
        p.setColor(0xffffffff);
        canvas.drawBitmap(ch, m, p);
    } else { // zoomed or cache unavailable
        ch = null;
        canvas.save();
        canvas.concat(m);
        v.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    // draw minimap
    if (showMinimap) {
        if (miniMapHeight < 0) {
            miniMapHeight = getHeight() / 4;
        }

        canvas.translate(10.0f, 10.0f);

        p.setColor(0x80000000 | 0x00ffffff & miniMapColor);
        final float w = miniMapHeight * (float) getWidth() / getHeight();
        final float h = miniMapHeight;
        canvas.drawRect(0.0f, 0.0f, w, h, p);

        if (miniMapCaption != null && miniMapCaption.length() > 0) {
            p.setTextSize(miniMapCaptionSize);
            p.setColor(miniMapCaptionColor);
            p.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawText(miniMapCaption, 10.0f, 10.0f + miniMapCaptionSize, p);
            p.setAntiAlias(false);
        }

        p.setColor(0x80000000 | 0x00ffffff & miniMapColor);
        final float dx = w * zoomX / getWidth();
        final float dy = h * zoomY / getHeight();
        canvas.drawRect(dx - 0.5f * w / zoom, dy - 0.5f * h / zoom, dx + 0.5f * w / zoom, dy + 0.5f * h / zoom, p);

        canvas.translate(-10.0f, -10.0f);
    }

    // redraw
    // if (animating) {
    getRootView().invalidate();
    invalidate();
    // }
}
```

}

```
public class DrawingView extends ImageView {

//drawing path
private Path drawPath;
//drawing and canvas paint
private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
//initial color
private int paintColor = 0xFF660000;
//canvas
private Canvas drawCanvas;
//canvas bitmap
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
private float brushSize, lastBrushSize;
private boolean erase=false;
private boolean moded=false;


public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    setupDrawing();
}

private void setupDrawing(){
    //get drawing area setup for interaction  
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
    lastBrushSize = brushSize;
    }

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
//view given size
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
//draw view

    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);

}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
//detect user touch  
    //check if editing or just touching it
    if(moded){
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
        drawPath.reset();
        break;
    default:
       // return true;
    }
    invalidate();
    }
    return true;
}
public void setColor(String newColor){
    //set color 
    invalidate();
    paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    }
public void setBrushSize(float newSize){
    //update size
    float pixelAmount = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
            newSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        brushSize=pixelAmount;
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    }
public void setLastBrushSize(float lastSize){
    lastBrushSize=lastSize;
}
public float getLastBrushSize(){
    return lastBrushSize;
}
public void setErase(boolean isErase){
    //set erase true or false 
    erase=isErase;
    if(erase) drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    else drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
    }

public void setMode(boolean isModed){
    moded=isModed;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
}
```

}